# What is the estimated cost for through hiking the Pacific Crest Trail?

Tags: hiking, united-states, pacific-crest-trail

We have a question about the [cost of through-hiking the AT](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7357/how-much-does-it-cost-to-thru-hike-the-appalachian-trail) and another about the cost of [through hiking the CDT](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/what-is-a-reasonable-budget-to-solo-hike-the-continental-divide-trail?noredirect=1&lq=1) but not one about the PCT which is the other big trail in the United States.

**What is the estimated cost of through-hiking the Pacific Crest Trail** (it's going to vary, but even ranges would be useful).

Answer (score 4):

Summary:

- Average monthly on-trail cost: $1,000
- Up-front gear costs: A complete PCT setup can be purchased for anywhere from a few hundred to a few thousand dollars, depending on quality level, pre-owned vs new, durability, and weight.

Long form answer:

The "average" figure usually provided by experienced thruhikers as a guideline for on-trail PCT expenses by is approx. $1,000 per month, and most hikers need about 5 months to get from Mexico to Canada.

The weather window for southbounders (Canada to Mexico) is shorter, and most sobo's try to finish in less than 5 months.

Many hikers find that it's not particularly difficult to hike the PCT on less than $1,000 / month, and (obviously) it's quite easy to spend significantly more.

This figure is for on-trail expenses only -- food resupply, town expenses such as restaurants, lodging, and laundry, and perhaps occasional gear repairs -- and does not factor in up-front costs for purchasing gear (tent, pack, sleeping bag/quilt, etc). A complete, very high quality ultralight setup for the PCT can be purchased, new, for less than $2,500.